# Difference between (int ret = 0; !ret && ret !=0)

Tags: c, if-statement, operators, expression

What the difference between:

```
1) !ret
2) ret != 0
```

?

```
if (ret != 0 || stack[fd] == NULL || stack[fd][0] == '\0')
{
  if (!ret && *line)
    *line = NULL;
  return (ret);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about `!=` and not `==`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a boolean context in C, a value of zero is considered "false" and a non-zero value is considered "true". Hence `if (ret)` (if `ret` is true) is equivalent to `if (ret != 0)` (if `ret` is not false), and similarly `if (!ret)` (if `ret` is not true) is equivalent to `if (ret == 0)` (if `ret` is false).

(i.e., the meanings of `!ret` and `ret != 0` are opposite, assuming the question is correct.)

Comment: The `if` statements in the examples are used to make the boolean context obvious (making the equivalencies valid by law of the excluded middle), but of course the boolean values of the expressions themselves are also equivalent in other contexts. The caveat is `ret` alone, which might not be a boolean expression if `ret` does not have a boolean type (the pattern `!!ret` is sometimes used to force a boolean context).

Answer (score 2):

They are exactly equivalent. (I assume you meant `==` instead of `!=` because otherwise they are each others opposite and definitely not equivalent in any way.) I would recommend the first one when `ret` should be treated as a boolean and the second if you're comparing quantities.

However, their counterpart is not equivalent. `ret` is obviously not the same as `ret != 1`, since any value except for 0 is treated as "true". This may seem like a nobrainer, but it can actually cause problems if you're using regular ints as booleans together with `#define true 1`.

Answer (score 1):

These two expressions are different

```
1) !ret
2) ret != 0
```

The first one yields 1 (i.e. true; in C there is no boolean type. The type `_Bool` is an integer type not boolean) when `ret` **is equal to 0**.

The second one yields 1 (i.e. true) when `ret` i**s not equal to 0**.

So in this code snippet

```
if (ret != 0 || stack[fd] == NULL || stack[fd][0] == '\0')
{
  if (!ret && *line)
    *line = NULL;
  return (ret);
}
```

In the first condition

```
if (ret != 0 || stack[fd] == NULL || stack[fd][0] == '\0')
```

there is checked whether `ret` is not equal to 0 (It can be equal to 0 but the if statement nevertheless will be executed due to other sub-conditions of the condition). While in the second condition

```
if (!ret && *line)
```

there is checked whether `ret` is equal to 0.

So in the inner if statement

```
if (ret != 0 || stack[fd] == NULL || stack[fd][0] == '\0')
{
  if (!ret && *line)
    *line = NULL;
  return (ret);
}
```

if the variable `ret` **is equal to 0** and the value of `*line` **is not equal to 0** then the expression `*line` is set to `NULL`.